# How are .xib files being automatically associated and loaded with my ViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm using Xcode 8 and Swift, not using Storyboards.

I hit Add->Cocoa Touch Class and check the box to generate a XIB.

I now have FooViewController.swift and FooViewController.xib. The xib has the class set under File Owner. As far as I can tell this is the only association between the XIB and the class. The generated class doesn't contain anything that loads a XIB.

I can create and display this view controller like so (from some other ViewController):

```
let foo = FooViewController();
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(foo, animated: true);
```

This works and it loads complete with the UI. What I don't understand is why. Most guides and tutorials online suggest that the ViewController needs to manually load a XIB.

- What is happening in the default initializer for FooViewController?
- Where is the XIB loading happening?
- What if I want to override it and load the XIB myself? (e.g. maybe I want to use different XIBs for different devices. Not the best practice, I know, just an example.)

Answer (score 0):

Back from the day in Xcode 4.5 when we used to create a Universal Application i.e.
for

1. iPhone
2. iPad

There used to be code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in AppDelegate Class to load different XIBs for target devices, so it did the same as you asked above. But given the evolution of Xcode and Cocoa Framework. It has come a long way from that where the compiler does a lot for us automatically.

Here in this specific scenario:

1. we have provided the file owner to XIB file, so when you are trying to present it, it goes ahead and searches in navigator/file available if a XIB is available for it, if it finds such a file, it loads the `UINib` from the bundle and loads it
2. if it doesn't it goes to the code to find if there is any
   programatic view being created while we do `super.viewDidLoad()`
   once it doesn't find anything, it generates a blank view for the same view controller.

If we look closely in the XIB file, there is a view outlet attached with main view available in the XIB but we have created no such outlet, so its connecting an autogenerated outlet for VC Source file with the view in XIB. If it makes sense.

Also please find some code below for reference from tableView Context:

```
let newAccountTableCellNib:UINib = UINib(nibName: "AccountTableCell", bundle: nil)
tableView.registerNib(self.newAccountTableCellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "AccountTableCell")
```

This should solve your query. Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks. How would I override this if I wanted to manually load the XIB for whatever reason? (While still associating the XIB with the class so that I can drag out outlets etc)

Comment: Going from your table cell example, I'm not sure how I would use a similar method to change the XIB of a ViewController. By the time `viewDidLoad` is called, the XIB has already been set.

Comment: Figured it out by looking at the comments of UIViewController. I have to provide an initialiser which calls the nibName:bundle version of super.init()